# How to install ngForce?

Tags: package-install, angularjs

I want to try ngForce - there is one problem though - I'm pretty new to Salesforce and I really don't know how to install it. Does anybody have any tutorial or howto with install steps explained?

I've searched the web and I can't find any decent one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FallenPhantasm,

Good morning. I'm the author of ngForce.

As it turns out there's a grunt task for installing it in your org. Once you've cloned the repo and run npm install just run:

grunt deploy

It will prompt you for username / password / security token. It will then build the latest version of ngforce, and upload it along with it's apex components to your org.

Comment: Gosh, it was there all the time, but I overlooked it, thank you for your answer

Comment: No problem man. I know my docs aren't uh, fantastic. Feel free to send a pull request referencing this or explaining the installation.