# ngForce integration to salesforce org

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, angularjs

I have gone through the videos and gitrepo which are suggested [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/angularjs-and-ngforce-more-fun-in-the-javascript-playground.html)

I clone this directory in my local drive, as you can see below
[image]

Now I follow the steps which are described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69974/how-to-install-ngforce)

1) rooted my cmd to the project dir 
   which is E:\Temo\ngForce-master
2) now I run "npm install".
3) After that I also run "npm install grunt-cli -g"
4) Now I run grunt deploy.
till now everything is working fine. it asked me for 
Username, password, and security token.
but I am getting below error in my console
[image]

please suggest me some way to integrate ngForce using grunt.
I have gone through many places but nothing helps me for this issue.
I will be grateful to you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to download Apache Ant, and make sure it's accessible in your %PATH% or $PATH environment variable. I presume you'll also need the migration toolkit library on your system. See Setup / Develop / Tools for links.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox but I just want to add something to this. after setup ant and migration library I also needed to update Gruntfile.js for the developer edition. I needed to replace the test.salesforce.com to login.salesforce.com. After that I got TSL 1.0 not configuration error. this error I resolved after update my java version from java 7 to java 8, and its all working fine now. I really appreciate your help.